# Schengen Visa Refusal: lack of evidence and high risk applicant

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, tourist-visas, pakistani-citizens

I am from Pakistan and applied for tourist visa to the Netherlands for just 15 days.The objection is that I do not have strong ties with my country. How can I satisfy the embassy and get visa?  Reasons are that I have not strong ties with home country and chances of illegal immigration.

Comment: tourist visa to where?

Comment: We don't know where you applied to for your visa and what your refusal notice said.  I have to mark your question as 'unclear' until you can add the stuff we need to get an answer out to you.

Comment: Tourist visa for Netherlands..Schengen Visa...Refusal notice said that you do not have strong ties with your home country and we are afraid off illegal immigration

Comment: I have voted to reopen, but you still need to tell us exactly WHICH boxes were checked on your Schengen refusal notice along with what they said in your letter (if you got one)

Comment: IT IS BOX NO 8 AND 9